# Tailwindcss makes bg-black/50 full transparent

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to create modal overlay with black rgba(0,0,0,0.50) by applying bg-black/50 but tailwind makes it full transparent rgba(0,0,0,0).

I check in chrome computed values.

Can anyone guide me to solution?

bg-black and bg-white are working fine but whatever color like bg-neutral-900/50 i apply with rgba do not work.

tailwind configuration is as below

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {   
    extend: {
      content: {
        'opening': 'url("/images/opening_quote.svg")',
        'closing': 'url("/images/closing_quote.svg")',
      },      
    },
    fontFamily:{      
    
      'oswald': ['Oswald', 'sans-serif'],    
      'sairaSC': ['"Saira Semi Condensed"', 'sans-serif'],
    
    }, 
    
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Not enough details. How have you set up tailwindcss etc.

Comment: @AndrewAllen tailwind config is added

Comment: Ok but how are you processing, e.g which setup from https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation are you using

Comment: @AndrewAllen I am using Tailwind cli, version "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",